# website is still in localhost

Tags: localhost

I upload my website to the server and I changed the website url and home from localhost to mysite url. But it still is in localhost if I turned off wampserver it won't show the website. Just show me when wamp server is on.

What should i do?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress hardcodes the domain into many of its permalinks in the database.

An easy solution is to download an SQL dump of the database on your host using phpMyAdmin or an SQL client, and then opening the SQL file in a (robust) text editor, assuming your database isn't enormous.

Then run a Find / Replace for the old domain (localhost) and replace with the new domain, and save the file. Then you'll need to execute the new SQL file on the database, so it is replaced with the same database with the proper domains in the permalinks

Comment: are you talking about the database which I upload to the host?

Comment: Yes you need to modify the database on your host since it uses the new domain. The database on your local machine should stay the same (since it uses localhost)

Comment: It's been long time I haven't work with this so I forgot it again. And now I have same problem. would you please tell me which file should I change. The file name I need to change the localhost.